# Kotlin array types and class literals

Tags: arrays, generics, kotlin

I am trying to deserialize an array of JSON objects with GSON. So the simple call:

```
val arrayOfFoo = gson.fromJson(source, Array<Foo<*>>::class.java>)
```

should do the trick. But type erasure tells us, that Foo<*> does not exist at runtime, so the error "Only class literals are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal" pops up. Well, so the solution must be:

```
val arrayOfFoo = gson.fromJson<Array<Foo<*>>>(source, Array::class.java)
```

Unfortunatelly, now the Kotlin compiler magic - that turns arrays of Wrapper types into primitive arrays - can not be sure what to do and tells us:
"Array class literals require a class type. Please specify one in angle brackets".

But, wait: This is, what did not work a second ago. Using

```
Array<Foo>::class.java
```

does not work, too, since now the compiler tells us: "One type argument is expected for Foo".

I personally can not see a way to solve that. Is it impossible to give a class literal of a typed array, which's type also expects a type parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem: You need to specify the type of your array. This is done using a `TypeToken` in Gson.

I hope this helps:

```
val listType = object : TypeToken<Array<String>>() {}.type

val json = """["1"]"""
val yourClassList :Array<String> = Gson().fromJson(json, listType)
print(yourClassList)
```

Note that for primitives, it is simpler: `Gson().fromJson(json, IntArray::class.java)`

Comment: Well, it is not what I hoped, because it does not explain, why it indeed works, if Foo expects no type parameter. But it definitelly works for me, so thank you.

Answer (score 13):

You can get the array class from an array instance, for example either one of

```
arrayOf<Foo<*>>()::class.java
java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Foo::class.java, 0)::class.java
```